# Animate a sine wave from the center

Tags: c, animation, math, wolfram-mathematica, data-visualization

I want to animate a sine wave as if it's generated from the center and moves outwards (to the left and right).

I started with this library: [SISinusWaveView](https://github.com/stefanceriu/SCSiriWaveformView) and made some adjustments. Currently I have this naive code for calculating the Y position of the curve depending on the X, phase and frequency:

```
float width = view.width; float mid = width / 2;
float adjustedX = x < mid ? x : width - x;
float y = maxAmplitude * sinf(2 * M_PI *(adjustedX / mid) * frequency + phase);
// phase increases every frame
```

Quite obviously, this causes a sharp angle at the middle of the sine wave, as seen below:

[image: sine-wave]

I would like to make it so the horizontal center of the animation is a smooth curve rather than a sharp angle, while keeping the animation horizontally symmetric. How would I approach this? Any mathematical insight for achieving this is appreciated.

---

*EDIT*

I tried to implement @TheBigH suggestion, but the parabola section is not seamlessly continuing the sine curve. Here's what I tried (implemented on *Mathematica* for quick visualization):

```
amp = 10;
freq = 1.5;
phase = 0.5;
Z = 1;
plotSine = Plot[amp*Sin[freq*x + phase], {x, Z, 2 Pi}];
aPara = amp*freq*Cos[phase]/(2 Z);
bPara = 0;
cPara = amp*Sin[c] - aPara*Z^2;
plotPara = 
  Plot[aPara*x^2 + bPara*x + cPara, {x, -Z, Z }, 
   PlotRange -> {{-Z, Z}, {-20, 20}}];
Show[plotPara, plotSine, PlotRange -> {{-2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {-20, 20}}
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Changing the sign of the parabola didn't quite work either:

[image]

---

*EDIT 2*

I see now that the problem was assuming `s(0) = p(Z)` and `s'(0) = p'(Z)`; instead of `s(z) = p(Z)` and `s'(Z) = p'(Z)`. Moving the sine wave so it would start exactly at the end of the parabole would fix the problem, but it's more convenient solving the parabola such as `s(z) = p(Z)` and `s'(Z) = p'(Z)` as that would simplify the implementation. How to do this?

[image]

---

*EDIT 3*

See this [math.stackexchange.com answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1061212/44743) for the final solution.

Comment: From the center, you could select the first extremum in the left half, the first extremum in the right half and connect them with a horizontal line. The curve would be smooth then, but perhaps this is not the desired effect.

Comment: @Codor: Thanks for your comment! However, I want the animation sides to be symmetrical.

Comment: You could separate the two halves by an equal offset from the center, then connect them with a section of a parabola.

Comment: @TheBigH: Sounds promising. Could you elaborate on how to calculate the suitable parabola section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OP has asked me to elaborate, here's my take as an answer.

Most generally, you're plotting the function `s(x) = a sin(bx + c)`, where `a`, `b` and `c` come from the original problem. Later we will shift the sine curve by some offset Z but I'll leave it out of the sine curve for now as it will complicate the mathematics.

The new parabolic section will have equation `p(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C` (`A`, `B` and `C` are different variables than `a`,`b` and `c`).

You want the two equations to join up cleanly, which means `s(0) = p(Z)`.  You also want the slopes to join up nicely so that there are no *corners*. That means you also need `s'(0) = p'(Z)`. Also, since the parabola is centered about the origin, `B = 0`.

Thus you have two simultaneous equations for `A`, `C` given that you already know `a`, `b`, `c` and `Z`

```
a sin( c ) = A Z^2 + C
ab cos( c ) = 2AZ
```

or

```
A = ab cos( c ) / (2Z)
C = a sin (c) - A Z^2
```

This gives you the equation of the parabola, which you plot between `-Z` and `Z`. Then all you have to do is plot the sine curves, now adding in that offset. Let me know if any of this is unclear.

*EDIT*: I see there is a vertical shift of the sine wave as well. This does not pose any problems; just leave it out to begin with and add it to the parabola and sine waves at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! However, I tried to implement it, but the parabola doesn't seem to seamless join the sine. See my updated question for details and graphics.

Comment: Somebody at [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1061212/44743) solved it with the `s(Z) = p(Z)` and `s'(Z) = p'(Z)` constraints. If you update your answer here I'll accept it, as you were the one who pointed me to the right direction. ;-)